# Microsoft Graph API - Unable to list meeting room places: place.read.all permission is required

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to get a list of room resources from the Microsoft Graph API using the list places endpoint at https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/microsoft.graph.room (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)).

I am getting a response back that says: `{"code":"invalid_permissions","message":"place.read.all permission is required to read company places, scopes/roles provided: Calendars.ReadWrite IsAppOnly:True"}`

I am getting this error from both the Microsoft Graph API Explorer and from a backend service using client credentials to access the data in a another tenant that has approved the requested scopes.

I have inspected the OAuth token and it includes the "Place.Read.All" scope from both the Microsoft Graph API Explorer and from my service:

For the Graph API Explorer

```
> jwt {access_token}
* Payload
{
  ...
  "scp": "
    Calendars.ReadWrite 
    Contacts.ReadWrite 
    Directory.Read.All 
    Directory.ReadWrite.All 
    Files.ReadWrite.All 
    Mail.ReadWrite 
    Notes.ReadWrite.All 
    openid 
    People.Read 
    Place.Read.All 
    profile 
    Sites.ReadWrite.All 
    Tasks.ReadWrite 
    User.ReadBasic.All 
    User.ReadWrite 
    email"
  ...
}
```

For my service

```
> jwt {access_token}
* Payload
{
 ...
 "roles": [
    "Place.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite"
  ],
 ...
}
```

Comment: +1 -- and I also can't find any workaround to this. The [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint returns rooms and users alike but there's no way to tell them apart; the v1 API doesn't have the concept of a room at all; the Beta API also has a [findRooms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) endpoint, but it's also broken because it doesn't include the `nextLink` value, so it can only return the first 100 addresses. How can one get a list of rooms of any sort?

Comment: What is strange is that this endpoint was working a few days ago, both in my service and in the Graph API explorer, and now I get this error. I am assuming its a bug Microsoft introduced but this is the only method I have of reporting issues :/

Comment: And yeah, I was hoping to use the list users endpoint as well but the `isResourceAccount` is always null :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use another api to get the locations.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRoomLists
GET /me/findRooms(RoomList='{room_list_emailAddress}')
It responsed a simple result, have not capacity info and the others.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the /me API endpoints do not work for my requirements. These endpoints require a token for a particular user. In my case we are using the client credentials oauth flow to gain access to an entire tenant's list of rooms.

Comment: Hi, this problem fixed now. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5666

Comment: Thanks, yep, there was also https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5640. If you want to post as an answer indicating it was a temporary issue with a link to both github issues, I'll accept it.